# How to select first element from Azure DocumentDB Query result

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am relatively new to C# programming and would like some assistance.

My Query from DocumentDB returns an object of the following type `{System.Collections.Generic.List<object>}` which has a count of 1. Is there a way I could just select the element at index zero without iterating over the variable?

Here is how the query string looks

```
return _dbclient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(dblink,"select * from c " + sb.ToString()).ToList();
```

I am not using entities FYI, the data is dynamic and therefore not mapped to objects

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Answer (score 3):

1.You could just sql : `SELECT top 1 * FROM c`

[image]

2.You could use `FirstOrDefault()` in sdk.

```
private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
private static readonly string authorizationKey = "***";
private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
private static readonly string collectionId = "item";
private static DocumentClient client;

public static async void QueryTest()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
            Item queryItem = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Item>(uri , "select * from c")
                                            .AsEnumerable()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("\nRead {0}", queryItem);
       }
}
```

[image]

3.You could set MaxItemCount =1 in FeedOptions parameter as @Sajeetharan said.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Would option 2 above retrieve more then 1 object from the db? (before selecting the first one I mean.. like select top 1 xxx instead of select * and then just use the first one)

Comment: @user230910 No,you could test it.